# Interpreting Feynman diagram of Coulomb scattering of positron

Tags: quantum-electrodynamics, scattering, feynman-diagrams, antimatter

I am trying to understand Coulomb positron scattering. [This](https://sites.ualberta.ca/%7Egingrich/courses/phys512/node94.html#cou) course explains that:

> [image]
> Here the incoming state is in the future and is to be interpreted as a negative-energy electron of four-momentum $-p_f$ running backward in time. Putting in plane waves to lowest order, the wave function is:
> [image]
> [...] Similarly, the outgoing state is the negative-energy electron running backward into the past. Its wave function is:
> [image]
> representing the incident positron with momentum $\vec{p}_i$ and polarization $\vec{s}_i$ before the scattering.

I can't wrap my mind around the meaning/interpretation of this. I know that antiparticles can be looked at as negative energy particles traveling backwards in time, so $-p_f$ makes sense. But in this situation, I don't understand:

- Why do we associate $-p_f$ to the initial state? Isn't the initial state the one on the bottom?
- If I want to compute the number of final states $dN_f$ in the range of the "final momentum", which moment/particle/momentum does this refer to?
- Why does the incident positron have momentum $+\vec{p}_i$, and is the outgoing state?

Overall, I think I need an insight on what happens in this process, as I don't have any intuition on how to interpret all this.